# Reliable sessions mechanism for JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, session, servlets

We have trouble implementing a nice session mechanism in JSP. One of our requirement is to allow only one session per user and not allow to open another which override the previous one. It means that we need a very reliable session system since losing your session means wait for the session timeout...
We have an issue with all session mechanism provided by the servlet :

- Url Rewriting : Everything works fine but... It avoids us to do caching stuff (mod_pagespeed cannot merge files; we are using a CDN...)
- Cookies : Of course we have some clients that blocks cookies...
- https Id : Not reliable, if the connection is reset, the session is lost. Some browser reinitialize the connection automatically. If you are using the website when you are moving (eg. from your mobile in the street), your connection will change depending on spot.

The perfect solution would be to use Rewrite+Cookie and to desactivate the rewrite for resources. Knowing that we have to use the c:url tag since our application will be installed on several domain.

Any idea on the perfect session mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard `Cookies`, `URL Rewriting` and `SSL Session ID` are the best standard ways to handle session.

Yes, you can definitely have your custom way of handling sessions if you can make out some `Unique id from a given request`. The Unique id you can deduce only from the one of the following request parameters:

- Request URL : URL Rewriting. A standard best way.
- Headers : Not possible with this. Clients cannot send custom headers
- Remote Socket Address: Which again is perfect because proxies in between.
- Cookies: A standard best way.
- Hidden Form Field : This will work only for POST requests.